# Return List<Object> from Linq SQL (Lambda) with join and where

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

In C#, I need to retrieve a `List<Object>` using linq with lamba expression.
This is the case:

```
List<TAB1> itemList = 
  context.TAB1.Join(
  context.TAB2, itm => itm.ItemCode, bcd => bcd.ItemCode, (itm, bcd) => new { ITM = itm, BCD = bcd })
                     .Where(i => i.ITM.ItemCode == (itemCode ?? i.ITM.ItemCode))
                     .Where(i => i.BCD.BcdCode.Contains(codeBars ?? i.BCD.BcdCode)).ToList();
```

At the moment that retrieves me a `list<AnonymousType>`, but I need a `List<TAB1>` that only return the values of that table.

**EDIT:**
The returned `List<TAB1>` needs to replace one property (`TAB1.Barcode`) with `TAB2.BcdCode` (it's the same type). How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `Select` statement after filters:

```
List<TAB1> itemList = 
  context.TAB1.Join(
  context.TAB2, itm => itm.ItemCode, bcd => bcd.ItemCode, (itm, bcd) => new { ITM = itm, BCD = bcd })
                     .Where(i => i.ITM.ItemCode == (itemCode ?? i.ITM.ItemCode))
                     .Where(i => i.BCD.BcdCode.Contains(codeBars ?? i.BCD.BcdCode))
.Select(i => i.ITM)
.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a new question:
If I want to replace one property of the TAB1 (`TAB1.CodeBars`) with one in TAB2 (`TAB2.BcdCode`), what I need to change in the select.